# How to Focus 3D View to Object Origin?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, customization, origin, keymap

I just did a fresh install of the newest Blender since I hadn't updated in quite a while but forgot about my essential custom keybind. I setup "Shift+J" as a focus on the origin of whatever object was selected. This was easier to me than moving the camera around manually but now I can't remember how I did it. I know it's buried somewhere in Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It was not in Preferences. Rather it was in "View", specifically the one in the top left of the 3D Viewport. Then I went to "Align View" and right clicked on "View Lock to Active" to input my shortcut.